# How to import existing java web projects with ant build.xml

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am trying to import an existing java web projects (built using ant build.xml) into Eclipse, using the Import functionality, but Eclipse does not recognize it as a project.

How can I import the projects into eclipse?

--- Edit --- 
What I did was to import the project as Java project. Yes there is an option in Eclipse 3.5 to import ant project into eclipse.
New Project -> Java Project -> Import Ant project(or something similar).

Comment: Can you tell me the directory structure of your Project ?

Comment: It's basically 
- build.xml
- src dir (has main->src etc etc )
- target dir (generated by ant)

Answer (score 3):

For Juno, do File->New->Other, then select File -> New -> Other, and at the New dialog, select Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile