# Importing a existing Web Application , into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I need to import a existing Web Application , into Eclipse .

Please  see the Structure of my Web Application as shown in the below figure .

http://imageshack.us/f/220/structurek.jpg/

From Eclipse IDE  , while using import What option i need to select that is should i use

1. Existing projects into Eclipse
2. Archive File
3. File System

please see this image 
http://imageshack.us/f/850/eclipseo.jpg/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Import existing projects into Eclipse` works only for projects that were created in Eclipse.

And you're definitely not dealing with an `Archive File` here.

`Import from the File System` just copies the resources but does not actually create an Eclipse project for you.

What I would advise you, is to create a new `Dynamic Web Project`, configuring all the required facets, and then just copy all the contents of your existing app to the `WebContent` folder, either by drag'n'dropping it into the `Project Explorer` or by using `Import from the File System`, overwriting all the contents.

So far, there seems to be no other way to do it in Eclipse. However you may check out the similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082256/how-to-import-existing-java-web-projects-with-ant-build-xml). The user @RC recommends using ant task for this process, but I'm more than sure that it won't configure all the required facets for you. It may work for some simple Java projects, but surely not enough for Java EE projects.